# How can I upgrade nginx after adding ppa:nginx/development?

Tags: server, upgrade, apt, nginx

I've installed nginx via the ppa stable repository via

    add-apt-repository ppa:nginx
    apt-get install nginx

which adds the stable release. But now I'd like to switch to the development branch, so I added

```
apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/development
```

and now even though it shows the newer version with `apt-cache show nginx`

```
Package: nginx
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Installed-Size: 92
Maintainer: Kartik Mistry <kartik@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Version: 1.2.0-1ppa1~lucid
Depends: nginx-full | nginx-light
Filename: pool/main/n/nginx/nginx_1.2.0-1ppa1~lucid_all.deb
Size: 58892
```

it still doesn't upgrade with `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Do I need to reinstall it after removing the stable source? Or is there any other way to just do an upgrade?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

Stable and development PPAs contain exactly the same version, so there's nothing to upgrade. See:

- https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable
- https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/development

You can remove stable source, nginx will be upgraded once there's newer package in development PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove nginx* && sudo apt-get install nginx
```